# Is it everyone or every one?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, punctuation

For context, is it "Everyone is here." or Every one is here." Thanks. I have found conflicting information in my research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context:

- [*Everyone*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everyone) means *every person* or *everybody*.
- *Every one* means *all of them*. It is used to refer to each item from among a group, and it can refer to things as well as just people. When using it, it normally follows from a more general statement.
  *All of them were contacted. Every one [of them] is here.*

So while both *everyone is here* and *every one is here* are grammatical and understandable, if it's a standalone sentence without previous context, then *everyone* is more idiomatic.

Also, if it's referring to objects rather than people (cars for instance), then *every one* would be used.